# code won't update when I change main.js in deployed firebase app

Tags: firebase, deployment

I have a variable that I want to update, but I already deployed my Angular app using Firebase. Using `Ctrl + F` in the `main.js` file, I manually found the variable and updated it. However, for some reason, the variable still doesn't change when I open the sources tab on DevTools. Is it supposed to take a while to update, or am I doing something wrong? Any response would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you deploy your angular app to Firebase Hosting? Did you use emulator?